# How to view changes made to a file (person used vim to make unauthorised changes)

Tags: apache, file

Is there a way that I can review the changes made to a file?

Basically, someone has logged onto my server and made unauthorized changes to a file, this has taken down a whole site. I want to see what the file read before the changes were made. The server is a standard install of centos and apache.

Unfortunately, this file lives outside of the svn (it's a config file).

Comment: First of all it's not related to vim, so I'll delete that tag. Second you can (and should) keep your config files under some revision control system (e.g. there is a package for that: etckeeper).

Comment: Like @Zsolt mentioned: Put it under version control. But the bigger problem you have is, that obviously authorized people have access to your server and are able edit files, they shouldn't be able to change ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the person used copy and cut in vim, and didn‘t clean the registers afterwards, you might find remnants of the changes with `:reg` in vim.

Which might at least make it easier to identify some parts of the file that were changed.

Answer (score 0):

In vim7.3 there is a setting that allows you to undo changes between sessions. You have to have in your .vimrc the following

```
set undofile
```

if you vim did  not have this setting there is no hope to recover what the original state of the file before editing it with vim.

If it was set then you can just type `u` in vim to undo the changes there were made.

The is a vim plugin, [gundo](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304), that allows you to have a nice visualization
of the past state of the file (again, you would have to have the option set, and the file were the changes are kept would have to exist).